# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UTILISATEUR' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, set, identity, savechanges, identity-insert

I use Visual Studio 2013 with Sql Server 2012.
I use [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/generating-views)
to generate views for my project. 
I have two tables:

1. UTILISATEUR (ID_UTILISATEUR,CIN,NOM,PRENOM...,ID_ROLE):
   *ID_UTILISATEUR* is primary key and *ID_ROLE* is the foreign key.
2. ROLE (ID_ROLE, NOM_ROLE, DESCRIPTION_ROLE): *ID_ROLE* is the primary
       key.

After the code generation process is complete, I have this:

- Controllers/UtilisateurController.cs .
- A new folder (Views/Utilisateur) : **Create.cshtml**, Delete.cshtml,
  Details.cshtml, Edit.cshtml and Index.cshtml .

My problem is that when I access to the Create.cshtml page, remply the fields and click **Create** I get the error: `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UTILISATEUR' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

It explains that I can't insert values to the identity column because it is set on ON. 
I don't know what I should change in the following code to resolve it.

---

My Create method in UtilisateurController.cs :

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ID_ROLE = new SelectList(db.ROLE, "ID_ROLE", "NOM_ROLE");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID_UTILISATEUR,CIN_UTILISATEUR,MATRICULE_UTILISATEUR,NOM_UTILISATEUR,PRENOM_UTILISATEUR,PASSWORD_UTILISATEUR,MAIL_UTILISATEUR,TELEPHONE_UTILISATEUR,ID_ROLE")] UTILISATEUR utilisateur)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UTILISATEUR.Add(utilisateur);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ID_ROLE = new SelectList(db.ROLE, "ID_ROLE", "NOM_ROLE", utilisateur.ID_ROLE);
        return View(utilisateur);
    }
```

The error line is: **db.SaveChanges();**

---

My Views/Utilisateur/Create.cshtml page is:

```
....
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_UTILISATEUR, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_UTILISATEUR)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_UTILISATEUR)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputCIN" class="control-label col-xs-2">CIN</label><div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CIN_UTILISATEUR)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CIN_UTILISATEUR)
        </div>
    </div>.....
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="créer" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>....
```

Please help !

Comment: Remove the Identity column to include say ID_UTILISATEUR and try one more time

Comment: I remove ID_UTILISATEUR from the code, but it doesn't work. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason you are getting this error is that you might have **altered/changed** the **PKEY column or data**. To fix, go to your ".edmx" file and right click on the table "UTILISATEUR" and select "**Update Model from Database**". This should work.